# Lottie animation dependency is not implementing successfully in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

**Gradle:app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.labawsrh.aws.introscreen"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.2.3'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'

    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.6.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting. Add error logs here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid asking questions that only contain code, you could improve your question, for example, by writing a summary of what your problem is, what you are trying to achieve, what you already tried to fix the issue, and by posting the stack trace.  This will make it easier for the community to better understand your question.